# Truncate table in DBeaver right click menu/GUI

Tags: dbeaver

I am trying to find an option to truncate table in the right click menu or somewhere in the GUI of DBeaver. The database is SQL Server.

Is there any other option rather that explicitly writing the truncate script?

Comment: Also searching for it, but for Postgres.

Comment: Right click on table name -> tools -> truncate (at least with Postgres)

Answer (score 18):

In DBeaver 7.2.4 - Right click on a table, that needs to be truncated, choose Tools->Truncate, click 'Start'. That's all.

[image]

Comment: The Truncate option does not show up in that menu for me.

Comment: It did showed up for me, I guess you have to highlight the table first then in the top bar menu Database -> Tools -> Truncate

Comment: DBeaver 7.3.5, there's no "Truncate" option in "Tools"

Comment: Sometimes truncate failes because of failing foreign constraints. To fix this on truncate dialog window do: "Truncate table parameters" -> "Settings" -> check "[v] Cascade" -> press [Proceed] button

Answer (score 3):

This feature is not yet available for SQL Server. May be DBeaver will include this in their new versions.

Comment: exactly this is the right answer. for SQL Server it's surprisingly not available...