# How to pull data from my production supabase database into my local supabase database

Tags: supabase, supabase-database

I have been trying to fix this problem, I could not search any documentation for this specific problem. I have everyhing setup, the project is linked, the docker is running, I just can not figure out the way to pull data from my production database in supabase portal into my database in local environment

Any form of help is appreciated

Comment: I understand the question is about pulling 'data', and not just 'schema' changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `supabase db remote commit` to capture any changes required for your local database to match the schema of your remote Supabase project.: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/cli/local-development#link-your-project

Comment: Following up on thorwebdev answer:
Be aware that if you do the supabase db remote commit it will not apply any changes you did to the AUTH schema or Storage schema. So if you have triggers or policies for those schemas then you have to write the SQL in that migration.

Comment: @Inb4cookies why is that? Can you point us to the documentation explaining this?

Comment: @carlesMitjans This was not supported in earlier versions. I think this is available now. https://github.com/supabase/cli/issues/96 since this issue is closed.

Answer (score 2):

[Link your local database](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/cli/local-development#link-your-project) then

`supabase pull`

`supabase db dump --data-only > supabase/dump-data.sql`

then run this sql on local database started with `supabase start`.

Usually it's `localhost:54322`, `postgres` db, `postgres` user, `postgres` password.

#### About another solution:

`supabase db remote commit` prints warning:

`Command "commit" is deprecated, use "db pull" instead.`

#### Consequent data dumps

...would sync records insertions but wouldn't sync records deletions.

To fix it clear target local tables before applying data dump.

For example you can achieve it with [DBeaver x-platform database client](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64819402/1760643).

Select tables to clear, right click, Tools -> Truncate, then on dialog window "Truncate table parameters" -> "Settings" -> check "[v] Cascade" -> [Proceed] button

Comment: The command `supabase pull` is an unknown command and returns: `unknown command "pull" for "supabase"`. Try `supabase db pull` instead.

Comment: this just misses details of how to get the dump into the local db